# Using the Split method

Tags: java, string

If I have a string like :

```
10.120.230.172  DOM1/HKJ    -   2010-11-04  08:05:30    -   -   10.120.12.16    -   80  410
```

I can use split to sepparate each item like :

```
String[] temp;
String delimiter = "//t";

temp = input.split(delimiter);
```

Normally I would be able to get :

```
String IpAddress = temp[0];
String user = temp[1];
etc ....
```

I get a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

What am I doing wrong guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delimiter should be `\t`, not `//t`

The former is a single tab character, the latter is a string containing 2 forward slashes and the character `t`

Answer (score 1):

Your delimiter is wrong (assuming you want to split on tabs). This should work:

```
String delimiter = "\t";
```